# Best way to count ActiveRecord child custom properties?

Tags: rails-activerecord

If I have a shopping cart, and in it is produce (where each produce has a custom expired property), what is the best way to count the expired property?  -- is there a better way than this count_expired?

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :produce, :dependent => :delete_all

  def count_expired
    count = 0
    self.produces.each do | produce |
      if produce.expired
        count ++
      end
    end
    return count
  end
end

class Produce < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cart, class_name: "Cart", touch: true

    def expired
        return <true or false logic>
    end
end
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the code DRY, so I didn't want to repeat the true/false logic in the parent.  But, maybe it should be there?   -- If it was in the parent, I could create check_expired() which accepts one Produce, or a list of them.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have posted this on a weekend.